# Can anyone help me with working examples of gregjacobs/Autolinker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, autolink

I am trying to make a text links on a page active hyperlinks. Every time new text links are added to the page via the form, I need the atolink script to rerun so newly added text links are also made active hyperlinks without reloading the entire page.

This is the form

Comment: try placing the script tag before the body tag ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `document.getElementById( 'testing' )` is returning `null`.. and you are trying to get `innerHTML` of null object..

It is returning null because your script is loaded before `<div id="testing">`. Move the script below it and it will work..

Comment: Is there a way to re-run the script every time any input is clicked?     I tried wrapping the script in a jquery

$(document).live("onchange",function()

to no avail.

Comment: how about writing a function and calling it from the `onClick` attribute of input..?

Comment: Unfortunately modifying the input is  not so much an option. If it was so easy I would look to modify the url's at submission time and not need javascript to rewrite plaintext :)

Answer (score 4):

Try placing the script before the body tag ends. The problem is script is executing before the tag is even rendered. Something like this should help.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="testing">
      http://www.test.com
      <br> @test
      <br> #test
      <br>
    </div>
    <script src="./dist/Autolinker.js"></script> <------ Also place the library at the end 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var myTextEl = document.getElementById('testing');
      myTextEl.innerHTML = Autolinker.link(myTextEl.innerHTML);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice thought, but no - that does however speed up the pageload time :)

Comment: Ahhh now I understand, yes your solution works perfectly, as did karthik's. This doesn't however address the comment I left under karthik's solution.

Comment: if you want to wrap everything and call it onclick of an input then you can do `$('body').on('click', 'my-input-identfier', function(){ ..// the autolinker snippet //.. });`

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.form_input_submit', function(){ var myTextEl = document.getElementById( 'bxwall' ); myTextEl.innerHTML = Autolinker.link( myTextEl.innerHTML ); }); --- Like this? Cause this totally broke the code.  --- My input button looks like <input class="form_input_submit bx-btn" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">

Comment: I'd say something like this http://jsbin.com/noyeje/2/edit?html,output Also I'm assuming you have a form wrapped around that button. But in the example I am not using a form. I hope it is clear

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in my situation. The form totally breaks and doesn't submit.

Comment: The example I gave above this will NOT submit form because I was using `e.preventDefault()` which will stop form submission. I used it only to show my approach. Anyways, I am assuming you got your solution for the question posted :)

Comment: RIght I understood that, Removing that line, makes my form work, but the script doesn't  reload with it.

Comment: Yeah, I understand we are going in a loop. I guess, if some more code was shared with us in the question and what exactly is happening/needed, would help us solve this problem :)

Comment: Well being as I can't quite figure out how to properly copy and paste code and such to this site, I guess I am just stuck.

Comment: This worked like charm to me. Hint: after breaking my head for an empty div with no content, I see my AdBlocker was hiding it. Just using `id="adcontent"` as variable name. 